# Как добавить пермишн на камеру чтоб проходило стандартную проверку?

Tags: java, android, камера, android-camera

Очень странная ситуация. Я работаю с камерой и у меня есть стандартный метод который открывает камеру

```
manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
```

так вот он стандартно требует, чтоб стояла проверка, вот она:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) !=
                PackageManager.
            return;
        }
```

Проверка достаточно простая, она проверяет заявлен ли запрос на разрешение использовать камеру в манифесте, вот такой

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

и если этого запроса нет то дальнейших действий не происходит и естественно метод который открывает камеру

```
manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
```

не срабатывает, так как он стоит после этой проверки.

Вот проблема в том, что разрешение в манифесте отмечено и когда я загружаю приложение на `Samsung S5` то все отлично работает, но когда я его загружаю на китайский телефон, то при открытии камеры он не проходит эту проверку.

Хотя один и тот же код, но на одном устройстве все работает, на другом не проходит проверку...

Может как то динамически добавлять пермишн??

И еще одно, я попробовал сделать так, прям в эту проверку поставить метод открытия камеры(подумал, может глюк какой то)

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) !=
                PackageManager.
            manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
            return;
        }
```

Но получил такую ошибку

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     Process: com.example.android.camera2basic, PID: 29649
>                                                                                     Theme: themes:{}
>                                                                                     java.lang.SecurityException: Lacking privileges to access camera service
>                                                                                         at android.hardware.camera2.utils.CameraBinderDecorator.throwOnError(CameraBinderDecorator.java:108)
>                                                                                         at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.CameraDeviceUserShim.connectBinderShim(CameraDeviceUserShim.java:336)
>                                                                                         at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCameraDeviceUserAsync(CameraManager.java:327)
>                                                                                         at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCamera(CameraManager.java:457)
>                                                                                         at com.example.android.camera2basic.activities.CameraActivity.openCamera(CameraActivity.java:919)

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Это может быть связано с новой политикой управления разрешениями, введенной в Android Marshmallow.

Для начала стоит переопределить метод обработки реквеста разрешения(т.к они теперь динамические):

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,  String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case CAMERA_PERMISSION:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ClassUsingCamera);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please grant camera permission!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
    }
}
```

А после этого попытаться задействовать камеру:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_PERMISSION);
} else {
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, ClassUsingCamera);
       startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

В андроиде 6.0 с разрешениями теперь работают по-другому

Ссылка на официальную документацию
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html